# How to add images to an Rmd Shiny document in a dynamic way?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have created a Shiny app based on an R Markdown document. Among other inputs, the user can select a 'type'. The `choices` for the type-`selectInput` are derived from the names of all image files located in the 'www' folder of the Shiny app (specifically, a subfolder named 'motives' within 'www'). When the user selects a type, the corresponding image file is displayed (of course other things are controlled by the type too).

The rationale behind this setup is that users of the app can easily add or delete types/motives. They simply need to place a specifically named image file inside a SharePoint folder, which is then synchronized with the 'www/motives' folder of the app. This eliminates the need for them to fill out lists with paths or contact the administrator (myself) to modify the set of types/motives.

The current issue is that the images only appear when the browser has previously resolved the image path (apologies, I'm not sure how to describe it any better). If I add an HTML comment (just a comment!) containing the HTML tags to display the images, it works. However, since users may add or delete images in the motives folder, I cannot hardcode these `img`-tags. Without the comment (type-b in the example) I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

What else can I do?

Here is the code of the example app saved as "app.Rmd":

````
---
pagetitle: "Test"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
# create image files just for this example app
png(filename = "www/motives/default.png", width = 200, height = 200)
plot(1:5, 1:5, type = "p", col = "grey", pch = 16, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
dev.off()
png(filename = "www/motives/type-a.png", width = 200, height = 200)
plot(1:5, 1:5, type = "p", col = "blue", pch = 16, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
dev.off()
png(filename = "www/motives/type-b.png", width = 200, height = 200)
plot(1:5, 1:5, type = "p", col = "red", pch = 16, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
dev.off()
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
# 
selectInput("type", label = "Type", choices = "default")
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
# get motives from all files in the motives-folder
motives <- data.frame(path = list.files("www/motives")) %>%
  mutate(title = gsub(".png", "", .$path))

updateSelectInput(inputId = "type",
                  choices = motives$title)

# create title output
title <- reactive({
  if(input$type != "default") {
    paste0("Special type '", input$type, "'")
  } else {
    "Default type"
  }
})

# create motive output
motive <- reactive({
  HTML(paste0('<img src="app_files/www/motives/', input$type, '.png" />'))
})
```

<h4>`r renderText({title()})`</h4>
<div id="motive">`r renderUI({motive()})`</div>

<!--- 
if this part is missing,
the motives are gone

<img src="www/motives/default.png" />
<img src="www/motives/type-a.png" />

the img tag for type-b is left out,
thus the corresponding image is not displayed 
--->
````

Default motive and type-a motive are displayed, type-b is not:

[image: Default motive is displayed]
[image: Type-a motive is displayed]
[image: Type-a motive is displayed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using "app_files" in the HTML paths to your images. You'll want to set that up in the document itself. I don't believe when you run a shiny document that it will automaitcally share your `www` folder. So you can explictly set that up with

```
shiny::addResourcePath("app_files", "www/motives")
```

You can add that to your setup chunk. Then when you go to use the image, use

```
motive <- reactive({
  HTML(paste0('<img src="app_files/', input$type, '.png" />'))
})
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. Is that the way I could add any other folder in the file system as a resource for the shiny app too? Might be better to manage the motives completely outside the shiny server directory.

Comment: Sure, you can use `addResourcePath` with any valid folder path on the server